# Sync problem with iTunes

Tags: synchronization

I have a Lumia 520 and I am trying to sync with iTunes on Windows 7. When I start the "Windows Phone app for desktop" program, it does not show anything from iTunes. I just get a "It's lonely in here..." message. I have checked the settings and it says "Sync music, videos and more from **iTunes**". I have the latest version of the application.

Comment: Here are a few things to try ([here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/cant-get-itunes-to-sync-with-wp8/24d87119-24ef-4b62-be32-8448733173b4) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/wiki/wp8-wpmusic/fix-sync-errors-between-windows-phone-and-itunes/9e16c540-10b3-4c66-9d3a-492cd2ed6c72)), taken from the MS Community site.

Comment: @NeilTurner - thanks. I tried those and no luck.

Comment: If your question here(http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/sync-to-my-windows-phone-hangs) includes the answer to this question (you used the WP app) you should probably answer your own question, saying how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually this was "fixed" by the latest version of the Windows Phone app and iTunes, but it took a few months before the two seems to play well together.

Even then, it would successfully sync once. Subsequent syncs failed when trying to delete files from the phone.

I should not be surprised, I've owned ms devices since the 90s and sync has always been a problem for them.